# Can't access the extra RAM of GoogleColab anymore

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ram

I tried crashing the session in order to get more RAM like I used, but it won't work

```
l=[]
while 1:
    l.append('nothing')
```

Has it been changed? What happened? Is there another way?
Please help!

Comment: If it was an exploit, they've probably patched it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now only available to Colab Pro.

You need to pay $9.99 to get that extra RAM.